# Why is the letter 'D' missing in the output?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    char ch1 = 'A';
    char ch2 = 'B';
    char ch3 = '\n';
    cout << ch1 << '\t' << ch2 << ch3;
    cout << 'C' << '\t' << 'D' << '\b' << ch1 << ch3;
    //return 0;
    system("pause");
}
```

Output is:

```
A        B
C        A
```

Why is the last letter A and not D?

Comment: Your output is [actually different](http://ideone.com/v5dRzc)?

Comment: `system()` requires `stdlib.h` or `cstdlib`

Comment: You explicitly tell it to erase the previous character using `\b`, how is this even a question then?

Comment: I'd like to second @JeroenVannevel's question... While the correct response has been given by many people, I'd like to (purely out of curiosity) understand _why_ the original reporter expected letter D to appear, whereas his code explicitly overwrites that with an A.

Comment: That's because the code is out of a book I'm using to learn this language and I didn't grasp what was happening.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Everything you `cout` gets outputted. It's just that a terminal will interpret `'\b'` as `"go back one character"`. Try redirecting the output to a file and examine it with a (hex)editor to see that all the characters (including `'\b'`) are there.

At a first glance, one might think that terminals print output as-is. That's incorrect, though. Terminals change the way they behave whenever they encounter one of special terminal control sequences or characters. The `'\b'` (=`0x08`=backspace) character is one of those. More can be found at http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php . You can try printing some of those to a terminal and see it change colors, rewrite current lines and so on and so forth. In fact, you can use these special sequences and characters to make complete GUI-like apps in the command-line.

Note however, that not with all programs you can rely on the `"redirect  to a file"` trick to see what terminal control sequences they write to stdout. Many programs detect whether they're writing to a terminal or not and adjust their usage (or lack thereof) of terminal control sequences accordingly.

Answer (score 11):

`\b` is a backspace, so you move the cursor one position to the left and then you overwrite the `D` with `ch1` which holds an `A`.

Answer (score 6):

```
cout << ch1 << '\t' << ch2 << ch3;
```

prints `A`, a tab, `B` and then a newline character.

```
cout << 'C' << '\t' << 'D' << '\b' << ch1 << ch3;
```

prints `C`, a tab, `D`, then moves the cursor behind `D`, prints `A`(This overwrites the character `D`) and then, prints a newline character.

`\b` is [an escape sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C) which represents a [backspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace). It moves the cursor one step behind.

Answer (score 2):

Others have explained why `D` is overwritten by `A`, because `\b` is the escape sequence for backspace.

I'd like to add that the output might be different on different machines. How `\b` is actually displayed is up to the implementation of the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the last letter A and not D?

Because the last visible character you output is `A`:

```
cout << 'C' << '\t' << 'D' << '\b' << ch1 << ch3;
```

`ch1` is `A`, `ch3` is a new line. And `D` is not shown because you erased it with `'\b'`

Answer (score 1):

What this line `cout << 'C' << '\t' << 'D' << '\b' << ch1 << ch3;` does is:

Print C,

Make space (tab \t)

Print D

Go back (backspace `\b`)

Print A where D was (D is now erased)

New line (\n)

Answer (score 0):

Because of \b jumping back and overwriting D

Answer (score 0):

Due to this line in code //'D' << '\b' << ch1 << , 
'D' will print D
'\b' is backspace, so D gets erased
ch1 prints value that is A